# Inverting a sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, inverse, sparse-matrices

I have a sparse, square, symmetric matrix with the following structure: (Let's say the size of the matrix is $N \times N$)

[image]

Here, the area under the blue stripes is the non-zero elements. Could someone tell me if there is an algorithm to invert this kind of matrix that is simple yet more efficient than Gaussian elimination and LU decomposition? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it is symmetric and positive definite you could try the Cholesky decomposition. Or if you have to use this for some kind of numerical calulations you might also want to look into incomplete LU/Cholesky decompositions.

Comment: So the entries are only on the diagonals? Or are the off-diagonal elements too? (I can't tell from your picture)

Comment: @RustyStatistician the entries is only a diagonal band (it has several non-zero elements per row).

Comment: Have you tried a banded LU algorithm? If the band is dense this will likely outperform a sparse LU decomposition